# Unable to locate a web element using protractor in jasmine framework

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I tried to locate an element on the page with the following but couldn't do.

```
element(by.css('.organizer-text.ng-binding')).click();
element(by.className('organizer-text')).click();
element(by.linkText('All Cases(1)')).click();
element(by.css('span[class="organizer-text"]')).click();
element(by.css('span[ng-class="{'folder-selected' : isSelected(node)}"]')).click();
element(by.css('span[title="All Cases (1)"')).click();
element(by.xpath('div//span[title()="All Cases(1)"]')).click();
```

Attaching the screenshot of the element with the DOM. Could you please help me on how to locate it?
[image: Snapshot]

```
<span class="organizer-text ng-binding" 
    tooltip="buildLabel(node.name, node.totalCases)" 
    ng-click="onLabelClick($event, node)" 
    ng-class="{'folder-selected' : isSelected(node)}" 
    ng-show="!node.showEditName" title="All Cases (1)">
 All Cases (1) 
</span>
```

The structure is `div->span->multiple` spans here (one of the spans here is the element)

Comment: improve code view and add inline image

Answer (score 0):

try

```
element(by.xpath('//span[@title="All Cases(1)"]')).click();
```

Comment: I guess it's just not the target element... Maybe there are clickable ancestor elements?

Comment: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.[0m

I included allScriptsTimeout: 30000

Comment: imed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 30001ms. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. The following tasks were pending:

Answer (score 0):

I used browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; after logging into the page and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found your answer yourself. But, this is for your own information. Just try this work flow out.

1. Right-click  of your element and get the inspect element window.
2. Go to inspect element of the element and right-click
3. There will be a window with some options
4. Select copy Unique Selector option.
5. `element(by.css('paste your Unique Selector here')).click();`
6. Like step 5 paste your unique selector

Hope this helps. :)